# Algorithm for primary decomposition of ideals in a power series ring over a field

Tags: commutative-algebra, computational-mathematics

Let $K$ be a field such that there exists an algorithm for factoring a polynomial over $K$ into the product of irreducible polynomials.
For example, the field of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is such a field.
Let $K[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$ be the formal power series ring over $K$.
Let $I$ be an ideal of $K[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$ generated by $f_1,\cdots,f_m$.
According to the well-known theorem due to E. Noether, there exists a primary decompositon of $I$.
Namely $I = Q_1\cap\cdots Q_r$, where each $Q_i$ is a primary ideal and this decomposition is irredundant.
Is there an algorithm to find generators of each $Q_i$?
If yes, I would like to know the reference.
Thanks in advance.

**Motivation**
There exists [such an algorithm](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717188800403) if $I$ is an ideal of a polynomial ring over $K$.
So it's natural to ask the above question.

Comment: It works the same way, the only difference is that the Groebner bases are called *standard bases*, because that is how Hironaka called them.